# Complex Object with words that express desire/intention and infinitive Verb in passive

Tags: grammar

**What is the way Complex Object shall be constructed if words that express desire/intention are used as predicate and infinitive Verb is in passive?**

a) I prefer it **to be done**.

b) I prefer **it done**.

c) I want shoes **to be polished.**

d) I want shoes **polished.**

Which out of two variants correct?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. **To be** can be elided or included in such examples. The choice will depend on preference and context.

For example, idiomatically: **The criminals wanted him dead.** would never take **to be**.

But **to be** is more likely in: **The artist wanted his paintings to be seen by the public.**

Comment: Ronald Sole, thank you!

Comment: Ronald, l think "want him to be dead" is not something wrong, neither is "want them all arrested". Nor is "want her seen by a private doctor". But yes in your last example it is more common to use "to be". @Irina I believe it depends on what the verb licences or allow.